# RegEx - Find Position of last found symbol in String

Tags: python, regex, string

i am struggling with regex in Python, i would like to find the position of the last token in a String.

Example: 
"mydrive/projects/test/version01"

Now i would like to get the position of the symbol between "test" and "version01"

```
import re
txt = "mydrive/projects/test/version01"
p = re.compile("/^.*/(.*)$/")
m = re.search(p, txt)
m.group(0) 
#but m.group(0) delivers None
```

but with this i am getting "None" i tried several things, but couldn't get it find the pattern. By the way i got this regex from a javascript page, but i think the patterns are the same.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say: Now i would like to get the position of the symbol between "test" and "version01".

I don't see how the regex is going to help you much. You could try the following:

Reverse scan for the symbol, if you know what the symbol is (I am assuming you do, since it is in the regex too):

```
>>> txt = "mydrive/projects/test/version01"
>>> txt.rfind('/')
21
```

If you don't know the separator:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> len(os.path.dirname(txt))
21
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `re` module in the wrong way.

You have 2 errors:

1. <s>You try to use a compiled regexp object as if it were a pattern</s> Actually this is perfectly fine, see [`search.sub`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).
2. Python's `re` doesn't need the slashes around the regexp.

Either use:

```
p = re.compile("^.*/(.*)$")
m = p.search(txt)
m.group(0)
```

Or:

```
m = re.search("^.*/(.*)$", txt)
m.group(0)
```

Comment: Passing a compiled pattern to `re.search` is perfectly fine -- just maybe not as fast as calling the `search` method.

Comment: @larsmans: Huh, it seems that you are correct. I'll edit my answer. This isn't documented for `search`, but it is for `sub`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: @cha0site as the python script is compiled on every change, this has no effect on performance. Furthermore this pattern doesn't give me the position of the token? Or do i have to call it? Thanks, but i got my answer from isedev.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious whether you're wanting to use `re` or are actually trying to split that filepath ?

`os.path` has all you need if that's the case, if not forgive me for answering a non asked question.

```
In [212]: import os
In [213]: os.path.split("mydrive/projects/test/version01")
Out[213]: ('mydrive/projects/test', 'version01')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the position of the symbol bewteen "test" and "version01" I'd just use [rfind](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind):

```
txt = "mydrive/projects/test/version01"
print txt.rfind("/");
```

which prints out `21`.